# What is the source of the expression המבין יבין?

Tags: sources-mekorot, words, hebrew, language, provenance

The Forward writer Philologos in [his most recent column](http://forward.com/articles/178044/its-a-hebrew-thing-you-get-it-or-you-dont/) claimed that the earliest uses of the expression והמבין יבין are found in the Ra'avad and in the Radak. Based on the fact that both these individuals lived in (late 12th century) Provence, he claims that the origin of the phrase is a Provencal translation of the New Testament. However, this expression is found earlier in the Lekach Tov (11th century Greece) and in the Ibn Ezra (early 12th c. Spain) as well as in many twelfth c. Ashkenazi works such as Rabbenu Tam's Sefer ha-Yashar, R. Yehuda b. Kalonymous' Tannaim ve-Amoraim, the Chizkuni al ha-Torah, and other places. This being the case, what is the most likely origin of the expression?

Comment: Interesting question. I'll be interested to see the response to the comments there that call the premise into question.

Comment: It seems that the original expression is המשכיל יבין, which appears in the Ibn Ezra about 20 times, and prior to that in תשובות הגאונים (presumably of Babylonian origin).

Comment: @wfb: in which case it might be based on ומשכילי עם יבינו לרבים (Dan. 11:33), although there יבינו is transitive.

Comment: @Alex: Interesting, & a lot more plausible for the Ibn Ezra to have had that in mind than a verse in the New Testament which means something else.

Comment: @wfb, I'm not sure it had to be used once originally.  Although it is an "expression," it means exactly what it is used to mean.

Comment: I don't have an exact quote for this, but isn't there an talmud phrase along these lines?  I keep thinking of  "מילף ילפינן" , but that's not quite it.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps this is the source - a take off from [Mishlei 19:25](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16390#v=25)

> לֵץ תַּכֶּה וּפֶתִי יַעְרִם, וְהוֹכִיחַ לְנָבוֹן יָבִין דָּעַת.‏

Comment: I hope you don't mind that I edited your answer; I think it's easier for people to have a link to verses quoted. If I did anything you don't like; it's your answer, you can always [edit] your own stuff.