# What is the practical application or message in the expression המבין יבין והמשכיל ידום?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, hebrew

Follow up to [this M.Y. question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29317/5275).

I think that I have seen Rash"i or perhaps the Gemarah use this expression, occasionally, Loosely the phrase translates as:

"The one that understands will, and the one that has insight will be silent."

I might be mistranslating some nuance, here in one of the words. However, I am curious as to why someone says this and what message their trying to convey. Usually, when I see this phrase, it has followed to rather complex explanation of something, and I still have trouble getting the gist of the explanation. It's as if the commentator is saying, "Well, most people won't really understand the point here, anyway."

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29317/759

Answer (score 1):

Basically it means that this is a phrase or explanation that can be easily misunderstood or can cause trouble for Jews if it is explained openly or translated. Thus, it is saying that someone who has learned sufficiently to understand the hint that has been given can understand the answer, but the intelligent person will keep silent and not go into more detail.